# Getting the number of elements within an HTML element (iframe)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, getelementbyid

I have been having some problems getting the information from a field using JavaScript.
What is needed is to see how many `p`s are inside the `div` that is inside the 'body' because I want to do some things with this number.

The HTML looks like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgEc4.png

The code that I have tried (I have been trying in the console in Chrome) - works sometimes, and sometimes it does not. I cannot seem to figure out why.

```
//Getting the iframe element
var testing = 
document.getElementById("radEditorCenter").getElementsByTagName("*")[2] || 
document.getElementById("radEditor_contentIframe");

//Getting the #document element
var innerDoc = testing.contentDocument || testing.contentWindow.document;

//Getting the html element
var HTMLElement = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("html");

//Getting body element
BodyElement = HTMLElement.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

When I try the last code snippet, it says

```
VM7957:1 Uncaught TypeError: HTMLElement.getElementByTagName is not a 
function 
at <anonymous>:1:27
```

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem was caused by a type. The function is called `getElementsByTagName` — Elements is plural — which you got right everywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to catch **all** p-nodes in body (and body's child nodes) you can use

```
var innerDocPnodes = innerDoc.querySelector('body').querySelectorAll('p').length
```